# Firestore Update Document field and get immidiate response issue getting old data

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to doing update firestore field value. It is updating, but I want immediately to use updated document. When I am getting those data that time, it will giving me old data from Firestore first time i hit the api. If I hit the same api twice, then I am getting updated data.

So, i don't understand what is the actual problem

```
updateProductDetail: async(req, res)=>{
console.log("reqeuest", req.body.creator);
try {
  var productFilterArray = [];
  var counter = 0;        
  let collectionRef = db.collection("product_details_temp");
  let query = collectionRef.where('creator', '==', req.body.creator).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No matching documents.');
        return;
      } else {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          db.collection("product_details_temp").doc(doc.id).update({ "product": req.body.product });
        });

        collectionRef.where('creator', '==', req.body.creator).get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            let  a =[];
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
              // a = doc.data();
              a.push(doc.data());
            });
            res.send(functions.responseGenerator(200, "successfull", a));
          })
      }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(
       functions.responseGenerator(error.code, error.message, error.data)
     );
   }
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have two operations:

1. A write operation
2. A query/read operation that must see the result of the write operation

Code that reads data from or writes data to Firestore runs asynchronously. And to prevent blocking the app, your normal code flow is allowed to continue while the read/write operations runs in the background. That means that the query/read currently runs in your code, the write operation hasn't completed yet, and hence you don't see the result of that write operation in your query.

The solution is to wait until the write operation has completed before starting the query. You already do this with the query, where you use the `.then(snapshot => {` construct to wait for the results. You'll need to do the same with the `update(...)` calls, with something like:

```
  let collectionRef = db.collection("product_details_temp");
  let query = collectionRef.where('creator', '==', req.body.creator).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No matching documents.');
        return;
      } else {
        let promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          promises.push(db.collection("product_details_temp").doc(doc.id).update({ "product": req.body.product }));
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
          collectionRef.where('creator', '==', req.body.creator).get()
            .then(snapshot => {
              let  a =[];
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                a.push(doc.data());
              });
              res.send(functions.responseGenerator(200, "successfull", a));
            })
        })
      }
```

The main changes here:

- This code captures the result of the `update` calls in a `promises` array. This gives us a list of promises, which resolve when the write operation completes.
- It then uses `Promise.all()` to wait for all write operations to complete before starting the query.

Comment: Thats's really cool :) Thank You Very Much @frank it is working

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, I tried the code in this way :

```
updateProductDetail: async (req, res)=>{
 try {
  db.collection("product_details_temp")
   .where('creator', '==', req.body.creator).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          db.collection("product_details_temp").doc(doc.id).update({ 
        "product": req.body.product });
        });

        controller.getAPI(req,res);

      });
 } catch (error) {
   res.send(
    functions.responseGenerator(error.code, error.message, error.data)
  );
 }
},

 getAPI: async (req, res) =>{
  try{
   db.collection("product_details_temp").where('creator', '==', 
   req.body.creator).get()
  .then(snapshot => {
   var A = [];
     snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        A.push(doc.data());
    });
     res.send(functions.responseGenerator(200, "successfull", A));
   }) ;
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(
      functions.responseGenerator(error.code, error.message, error.data)
    );
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this issue by using the setTimeout() function:

```
setTimeout(() => {
          collectionRef.where('creator', '==', req.body.creator).get()
          .then(snapshot => {
           let a = [];
           snapshot.forEach(doc => {
           a.push(doc.data());
         });
        res.send(functions.responseGenerator(200, "successfull", a));
     })
    }, 2000);
```

Use this with code like:

```
updateProductDetail: async(req, res)=>{
  try {
     let collectionRef = db.collection("product_details_temp");
     let query = collectionRef.where('creator', '==', req.body.creator).get()
         .then(snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {
                   console.log('No matching documents.');
                   return;
                } else {
                   snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                   db.collection("product_details_temp").doc(doc.id).update({ 
                   "product": req.body.product });
                  });
                }

      setTimeout(() => {
              collectionRef.where('creator', '==', req.body.creator).get()
              .then(snapshot => {
               let a = [];
               snapshot.forEach(doc => {
               a.push(doc.data());
             });
            res.send(functions.responseGenerator(200, "successfull", a));
         })
        }, 2000);

      })
   } catch (error) {
        res.send(
           functions.responseGenerator(error.code, error.message, error.data)
        );
   }
```

Comment: Please don't use timeouts to solve race conditions in asynchronous code. At best you're making the code wait longer than needed, at worst this won't work for a user who's on a slower connection.